# SAS dd-mm-yyyy to mmm-yy format like excel

Tags: sas

I converted the date 01-01-2020 to Jan-20 in SAS by using the below proc format:

```
proc format;
    picture date9x other = '%b-%0y'( datatype= date );
        format MMYYYT date9x.;
run;
```

This works fine but when I export the SAS value of this date shows up in the field. Is there any better way to convert to MMM-YY?

Comment: Explain what you mean by EXPORT.  Note that a format does not change the value stored. It just changes how it is displayed.  The same thing happens in Excel.

Comment: The solution changes depending on how you exported your data?

Comment: Right, the values in my dataset did not change. Only the format changed. However when I export them to excel I noticed that the fields now has SAS date value instead of MM-YYYY. Ultimately I want to convert (01-01-2020 or 20200101) to display as Jan-20 when I export the sas dataset to excel file.

Comment: There are multiple ways to export, explain in detail what you did.  If you used code show the code. If you used menu item explain what user interface you are using and what menu items you used.

Answer (score 3):

`Proc EXPORT` will use a default Excel data format, m/d/y, for any data set column formatted with a SAS date format. Export will replicate the SAS format with a 'nearest' corresponding Excel date format.

ODS Excel will apply Excel formatting to date formatted variables so as to correspond to the same look in SAS.

As for `mmm-yy`, or `Jan-20`

The SAS format `monyy` gets you close, but there is no option to insert a separator (`-`).  However, ODS Excel destination will honor Excel formatting directives specified in the style option `tagattr=`.

Example:

```
data have;
  date  = '01-JAN-2020'd;
  date2 = '01-JAN-2020'd;
  format date date9.;
run;

ods excel file='want-ods.xlsx';
proc print data=have;
  format date monyy5.;
  var date;
  var date2 / style=[tagattr='type:DateTime format:MMM-YY'];
run;
ods excel close;

options noxwait noxsync xmin;
%sysexec start "preview" want-ods.xlsx;
```

SAS view of data set
[image]

Excel view of data set printed through ODS Excel, with Proc time formatting and styling.
[image]